# Is it possible to increase hard disk space on virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have **Ubuntu** which runs as virtual machine under **VMware Player** .

When I installed Ubuntu I allocated 5 GB for its Hard Disk .

Is it possible to increase this space retroactively without re-installing this virtual machine?

I work with VMware player -  `Version : 5.0.0 build-812388`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

There are at least two ways to do it:

1. Easiest: Add an extra virtual disk.
2. Grow the VMDK and do some arcane SCSI rescan magic followed by increasing the filesystem.

Personally I always used option 1. Both because it is the easiest way and because it allows me to keep a few partitions (such as /home/, /usr/local/, ...) on a separate VMDK 'disk'.

Option 1 is trivial if you use vmware workstation. You can download it for free and use it up to 30 days (trial).

An other way is to manually edit the config files and somehwo create a second .vmdk file. For the configuration changes look at the .vmx file. You want to add lines similar to these:

```
 ide0:1.present = "TRUE"
 ide0:1.fileName = "My_new_extra_disk.vmdk"
```

You should already have at least one entry for a disk. You can just copy that and slightly change it.  (If emulation is set to SCSI, just copy the SCSI disk part).

To create the vmdk either copy an already exiting file, or reate a new one (e.g with vmware workstation or oracle virtual box).

Answer (score -1):

I recommend Oracle's [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). While setting up your VM you have the option to select dynamically expanding while choosing Hard Disk size.

Comment: It works, I love VirtualBox, but it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: How would I improve it? or what needs to be changed? add instructions on how to transfer and setup the vmdk on VirtualBox?

Comment: The OP wants to use VMware and not VirtualBox, so your answer should assume that. If it's possible to expand the disk size with VirtualBox and still use the VM, that'd be helpful, but please [edit] your answer and be more specific. Thanks!